# xcode change target from 'iOS device' to the simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I had a project in xcode and didn't touch it for a month (and forgot how it works).

Now I want to change the target from 'iOS device' to the simulator.

I can not for the life of me figure out how I should do this in xcode 4.5.2

-- EDIT FOR CLARITY --

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is well-hidden, until you figure it out (see Jacky's answer).  (Yet another "What *were* they thinking??" aspect of the newer Xcode.)

Comment: Yes, except that this won't work this time (see my comment on his post)

Comment: Did you click on the right-hand side?

Comment: Have you installed a simulator compatible with your current project ? (Preferences > Downloads > Components) This should be done for you, but who knows …

Comment: Solved. Weird how these components just disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have any simulator installed in your X-Code. (Xcode->Preferences -> Downloads -> Components )

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Top left corner in Xcode: Set Active scheme.

Comment: Nope. 'iOS Device' is the only one that pops up.

Comment: Note that you must click on the right-hand side of the Scheme bar for this.  (Great intuitiveness, no?)